# Convert complex HTML file that has CSS styles into a PDF file in Android

Tags: android, html, pdf

I have a requirement where by I need to convert a complex HTML file that has `CSS` styles into a PDF file in an Android app. I tried using `IText` library for Android but it is not able to interpret the `CSS` styles and some of the tags. I have searched a lot, and haven't been able to find a library that meets my requirement.

Is there any other library for converting HTML file to PDF in Android?

Below is my html file c5.html

```html
<div id=divCont style="left:0px;top:0px;width:auto;height:569px;">
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Name" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:210px;margin-top:45px;width:252px;height:27px;"> #Name-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Age_Gender" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:210px;margin-top:82px;width:252px;height:27px;"> #AgeGender-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Diagnosis" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:210px;margin-top:151px;width:252px;height:52px;line-height:0.5cm;"> #Diagnosis-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Note" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:17px;margin-top:120px;width:102px;height:252px;line-height:0.7cm;">#Note-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Rx_Text" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;padding-bottom:15px;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:245px;margin-top:249px;width:277px;height:252px;line-height:0.7cm;">#Prescription-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Additional_Information" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:210px;margin-top:517px;width:277px;height:52px;line-height:0.7cm;">#AdditionalInformation-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Date" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:1px;margin-top:5px;width:122px;height:27px;">#Date-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Signature" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;padding-bottom:5px;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:10px;margin-top:574px;width:122px;height:27px;">#Signature-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_DrName" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;padding-bottom:5px;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:12px;margin-top:645px;width:150px;height:25px;">#DrName-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_MedDocket_Id" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:210px;margin-top:2px;width:252px;height:32px;">#MedDocketID-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_doctor_RegistrationNo" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:8px;margin-top:507px;width:172px;height:27px;">#doctor_RegistrationNo-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Patient_Address" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:1px;margin-top:63px;width:202px;height:52px;">#Patient_Address-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Weight" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:210px;margin-top:114px;width:72px;height:32px;">#Weight-Data#</div>
   ##
   <div id="draggable_Prescription_SerialNo" class="ui-widget-content" style="border: 0px solid black;position:absolute;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;margin-left:1px;margin-top:32px;width:122px;height:27px;">#SerialNo-Data#</div>
   ##
</div>
```

Below is the code I used to convert my html to pdf file.

```
private void createPDF(File pdfFile) {
     // create a new document
     Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
     try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
         PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
         document.open();

         File htmlFile = new File(docDir, "c5.html");
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(htmlFile);
         String html = convertStreamToString(fis);

         InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes("UTF-8"));

         // get the XMLWorkerHelper Instance
         XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
         // convert to Pdf
         worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, stream);         
         // close the document
         document.close();
         // close the writer
         pdfWriter.close();

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
         intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
         startActivity(intent);
     } catch (DocumentException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Show us the css and html that gives you issues, and the code you use.

Answer (score 0):

check out Class jsPDF, the newest version is v1.81 (2015-12-20

http://www.fpdf.org/en/download.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply mlegg, but I have to convert html file to pdf file in my android app. So Php libs i.e fpdf or jsPDF is not useful to me.

Comment: have you tried this?  [url to pdf]https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nop.urltopdf&hl=en

Comment: here is a link with the top 5, this year, https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-creating-tips/android-web-to-pdf.html

Comment: I have to fetch html code from my sqlite database and convert it to pdf in my Android Application.

Comment: how did it cone out?